# chrome extension what's the use of argument: tabld?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm learning how to write a chrome extension.

in most of the apis, there is a argument: tabld.

I can't understand what is it used for.

for example ,function chrome.browserAction.setIcon's description is [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setIcon)

I searched all over the internet and chrome extension documents, there is not even a example there, just a sample describe said:

> tabId ( optional integer ) Limits the change to when a particular tab
>   is selected. Automatically resets when the tab is closed.

what this argument used for? can anyone give me a example of it ?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each tab in Chrome has unique ID which resets after browser restart. It is useful when you want to identify tabs.

In 99% cases you will be interested only in currently selected tab because it is where a user is right now. You can just pass `null` instead of `tabId` to almost any method and it would mean you want selected tab id. Same with window id - passing null usually means current window.

Otherwise you can get selected tab with `chrome.tabs.getSelected`, which returns `tab` object containing `id`. You can get all tabs with their ids with `chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow`.

Comment: Oh,,It's tab"I"d, I thought I was tab"L"d which I can't understand what's it's meaning. thank you @serg, now I get it's meaing.